# Intransitive verbs that take Indirect objects

Tags: syntax, verbs, grammatical-object, transitivity

Can there be intransitive verbs which take an indirect object? 
In the sentence "It pleases me" is "me" an indirect or direct object?
What languages frequently have indirect objects in a sentence without direct objects?

Comment: Which linguistic framework?

Comment: In English "It pleases me" is clearly a transitive verb taking a direct object. In Latin "mihi placet" is a verb taking an indirect object, but whether you call it transitive or not depends on what definition of "transitive" you choose.

Comment: In my understanding indirect objects are really only used in ditransitive clauses. Maybe there's a framework which allows indirect objects without direct objects, but I'm not familiar with them. That's why we need more clarification :)

Comment: @curiousdannii You raised an interesting question. I think that indirect objects can be established on a the pure descriptive (pre-theoretical level). Suppose you have a language that is morphologically ergative, but also features a class of verbs that take an absolutive subject and some other argument. Or do you mean that a theory-specific diagnostic of subjecthood is necessary anyway to say that an absolutive is the subject?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov I was saying that there's no objective answer - it all depends on how you analyse it depending on which framework you use.

Comment: sorry, i didn't make myself clear. I just was contemplating a framework-independent approach :)

Comment: @IvanKapitonov Then you'd just be making your own new framework.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov, There's no such thing as "framework-independent approach." cf. "Всякое утверждение обладает научной ценностью только при том условии, что оно делается в контексте теории" (Звегинцев 1973/2009: 4).

Comment: It seems to me that this very sentence is intransitive with an indirect object.

Comment: I'm voting to close that this is too opinion based because it all depends on how you use the term indirect object.

Comment: @curiousdannii all terms always depend on how you define them. Please elucidate how we are supposed to ask questions without terms.

Comment: @MaxP I'm not saying that you shouldn't use terms, but that if you're going to use them in unusual ways (or are asking about terms which appear to have multiple conflicting definitions) then you need to be specific about that. I've never heard of any linguistic framework in which it is meaningful to talk about the indirect objects of intransitive verbs. So the OP is either confused, referencing an uncommon framework, or inventing their own. In all cases more clarification is needed.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have never heard of that framework seems like a curious reason to close a question, especially if you appear to be the only one who whas never heard of it.

Comment: @MaxP What do you mean you've never heard of that framework? The problem with this question isn't that it can't be answered, but that without the OP being more specific it can only be answered with opinions. One person can say yes according to their framework, another will say no according to their framework. Additionally I think the question is based on a faulty understanding of these terms. But *if* the OP is using some framework where the terms have a slightly different usage and the question makes sense, then great. *But they need to edit it to make it clearer!*

Comment: Seriously, what kind of theory labels a verb with an object (whether direct or indirect) 'intransitive'? Why does the OP think that "It pleases me" has an intransitive verb?!?

Answer (score 2):

**Serbian** has something like that, if I am understanding you right. Some Serbian intransitive sentences can still have dative, genitive and/or locative arguments; an example for this would be `она му[D] прича (о кући)[L]` (*she is telling him about the house*) where there's both a dative listener `му` (to him) and a locative topic `о кући` (about the house).

We are certain that neither of these is a direct object because 1) neither is in either the genitive or the accusative (Serbian DOs must be in either one of those cases) and 2) neither can be made into the subject of a passive verb form: sentences such as `*он је причан о кући` (*he is told about the house*) and `*кућа је причана њему` (*the house is told to him*) do not work and sound quite ungrammatical. The only passive sentences these two arguments could fit in would be in the spirit of `причано му[D] је (о кући)[L]` (*it was talked to him about the house*) and those kinds of sentences still retain both the locative and dative arguments.

Furthermore, it is possible to add an accusative into the example sentence, thus for example giving: `она му[D] прича причу[A] (о кући)[L]`. Such a sentence can easily be turned into a passive one, giving f.e. `причана му[D] је прича[N] (о кући)[L]` where the former accusative argument "причу" becomes a nominative argument "прича" in accordance with general passivisation patterns in nominative languages.

The only way these sentences could be analysed as including a direct object would be to analyse them as having a dropped or implied accusative argument, which is otherwise unheard of in Serbian.

This also has a parallel in sentences with a non-nominative subject; a sentence with a genitive, accusative or dative subject is usually intransitive, but can also have additional arguments that do not serve as direct objects.

With a genitive subject, these are most often sentences in the mould of `нема нам[D] посла[G]` (*there's no job for us*) or have an experiencer (such as `тебе[G] ме[G] је срамота` *it's you who I'm ashamed of*; this sentence has two genitive arguments). With a dative subject, they are usually those with experiencers, such as `хладно му[D] је` (*he feels cold*, more directly *it's cold to him*). With an accusative subject, they also usually are with experiencers, such as `жао ми[A] је детета[G]` (*I feel sorry for the child*).

Such sentences with non-nominative subjects and additional arguments but without a DO still cannot be passivised. They'd give sentences like `*посао нам нема`, `*срамотан сам тебе` and `*жао сам те`; these sound utterly wrong and ungrammatical. The closest equivalents would have to use different verbs or phrasings for that, giving `немамо посла` (*we don't have a job*), `тебе се срамотим` (*it's you who I'm ashamed of*), and `жалим дете` (*I pity the child*), which are all sentences with DOs and a dropped pronominal subject.

Comment: жао ми[A] је детета[G] - 'mi' is here dative, not accusative - the A is 'me'.

Answer (score 2):

Under the traditional interpretation of the terms 'transitive' (= capable of taking a 'direct object') and 'intransitive' (= not allowing a 'direct object'), the answer is 'Yes'. Spanish is a case in point. In Spanish sentences parallel to *It pleases me*, such as (1) or (2)

1. El discurso del Rector ME/NOS/TE/OS/LE/LES gustó.
2. ME/NOS/TE/OS/LE/LES gustó el discurso del Rector.

the clitic pronominals are in the **dative** case and, in Spanish, where, contrary to Modern English, the dative/accusative contrast remains relevant, must be analysed as **indirect** objects (and, of course, cannot be converted into subjects of passive sentences, etc.). This fact does not show when the clitics are first or second person, as in that case the Spanish dative and accusative forms are, as in English, also homonymous and indistinguishable (i.e., *me/nos, te/os*), but it does show very clearly when the clitics are third person: *LE/LES gustó el discurso del Rector* (with dative clitics > indirect objects) are fine, but *LO/LA/LOS/LAS gustó el discurso del Rector* (with accusative clitics > direct objects) are terrible.

Comment: (+1 if I could vote) A mí me gusta mucho ese explicación. There is also the Hebrew existential /yeʃ/ used for possession as in /yeʃ li/ 'I have', lit. 'There is to me'. And many English "flip predicates" like [_sound_ as in _That sounds odd to me_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299).

Answer (score 1):

Latin *uti* "to use" takes an ablative complement: *aratro utor* "I am using a plow".

Comment: It may have the ablative case, but what evidence is there that it is an indirect object?

Comment: The fact that it is not in the accusative case (the case normally associated with direct objects).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. In German, for example, the verb "helfen" (to help) is intransitive: "ich habe ihm geholfen" (I helped him). It takes an indirect object (dative) that can't be passivized.

Turkish has many verbs with so-called noncanonical (indirect) objects where one would expect a direct object. In general, just get a valency lexicon of any language and look for frames of intransitive verbs, you'll find many slots for indirect objects.

Comment: Your claim that "helfen" cannot be passivized is wrong. "Dem Mann kann geholfen werden" (Schiller).

Comment: @fdb What I meant is that the object can't be passivized - one can't say Der Mann wurde geholfen. The verb as such can be passivized of course. Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the formulation.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. In normal linguistic parlance you can say that a verb is "passivized", but you cannot really say that about a noun.

Comment: It may take a dative case, but what evidence is there that it is an indirect object?

Comment: @curiousdannii It can't an anything else (unless you have a really weird definition of indirect object).

Comment: @Atamiri That's why I think this question is not clear enough/too opinion based. I wouldn't only ever label something an indirect object if the verb was ditransitive - otherwise it's just a verb that assigns a different case than normal.

Comment: @curiousdannii That is not the traditional definition. The German grammar tradition comes from Latin linguistics where it is an indirect object.

Comment: @Atamiri You're only proving my case. If individual languages have different understandings of what an 'indirect object' is then the question needs to be more specific.

Comment: @curiousdannii "Tell me" is a correct English sentence, consisting only of a verb (imperative) and an indirect object. "Tell me the truth" consists of a verb, an indirect object and a direct object.

Comment: @fdb Or 'tell me' could be analysed as having a direct object. For 'tell me the truth' I'd call 'me' the DO and 'the truth' the IO.

Comment: That is a total inversion of the universally accepted definition of "direct" and "indirect".

Comment: @fdb It does appear that I'm incorrect. (I still think my understanding makes much more sense. Note to self: never use the term indirect object.) But it makes no sense to me to talk about an IO except in ditransitives.

Comment: Indirect objects aren't really objects at all. Describing something as an object indicates that it is the thing that receives the action of the verb but Indirect object seem to universally take an adverbial role - they describe the direction of the action. They are both verb complements but the so called indirect object forms an adverbial relation and the direct object forms an object relation. *I gave the book to him.* - *to him* says where the action happens (or in what direction). In *I gave him the book*, him is still creating an adverbial relation.